# Sobolev imbedding on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces

Let $(M, g)$ be a non-compact smooth Riemannian manifold of dimension $n \ge 2$, and $G$ a subgroup of the isometry group of $(M,g)$, say with $G$ contained in the component of the identy.

Let $W^{1,2}_{G}(M)=\{f \in W^{1,2}(M)| \quad f\circ \phi =\phi \quad \forall \phi \in G\}$.

Is there any known result concerning the compactness of the Sobolev imbedding $W^{1,2}_{G}(M) \hookrightarrow L^p(M)$ for some subgroup  $G$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\textrm{dim}\,G<\infty$? As I recall, the isometry group of a Riemannian manifold is finite dimensional.

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake. What I meant is: $G$ contained in the component of the identity

Comment: You should not take the same letter for the metric and for elements of the group.

Comment: There is an old note by Naceur Achtaich (circa 1988) when $M\subset\mathbb R^3$ has a rotational symmetry about the $z$-axis. Very localised, but at least an exmple.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for posting this as an Answer, but I can't comment yet.

As far as I know (judging from Emmanuel Hebeys work on this subject), there are no generalised results on Sobolev embeddings on non-compact Riemannian manifolds unless they are complete.

Answer (score 2):

Hi, 
You need additional geometric condition for the general case but considering the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $G=SO(n)$, i.e. $H^1_ {radial}$, you have compact injection. You will find all the details in chapter 9 of the excellent book of Hebey *Nonlinear Analysis on Manifolds: Sobolev Spaces and Inequalities*.

Comment: I'm quite new in this field, but in the new book by Hebey [Sobolev spaces on Riemannian manifolds] he only considers the case when $M$ is compact. Anyhow, I have to the reference you've just mentioned.

Comment: I give you the precise reference, it is also about non-compact case! you have just to read...